# What is the best way to create value objects?

Tags: php, validation, value-objects

I'm wondering how to in the best way create value objects.

For example:

I have value object Password

```
class Password
{
   private string $password;

   public function __construct(string $password)
   {
      $this->password = $password;
   }

   public function __toString(): string
   {
      return $this->password;
   }

}
```

And now I wonder how to correctly validate this.

VO should always have the correct value. Should I validate the passed value due to creating an object?

For example:

```
class Password
{
   private string $password;

   public function __construct(string $password)
   {
      $this->validate($password);

      $this->password = $password;
   }

   public function __toString(): string
   {
      return $this->password;
   }

   private function validate(string $password): void
   {
       if(!validation_rule)
       {
         throw new InvalidPasswordException();
       }
   }
}
```

Or should I use the factory?

```
class PasswordFactory implements PasswordFactoryInterface
{
    private PasswordValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(PasswordValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function createFromString(string $password): Password
    {
        $this->validator->validate($password);

        return new Password(password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST));
    }
}
```

My conclusions:

Validation due construction:

**Advantages**

1. I will not create an invalid object.
2. Less code.

**Disadvantages**

1. I cannot use dependency injection for external validators.

Validation in factories:

**Advantages**

1. I can use external libs for validations with Dependency Injection.
2. Imho easy to test.
3. Hermetized operation. If I have to change the constructor I will change invocations only in the factory.

**Disadvantages**

1. I allow to create an invalid object if someone won't use the factory.
2. More code.

I thought also about passing validator to named constructor

```
class Password
{
   private string $password;

   private function __construct(string $password)
   {
      $this->password = $password;
   }

   public static function createValidated(string $password, PasswordValidatorInterface $validator): self
   {
      $validator->validate($password);

      return new self($password);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value object should always be instantiated in a valid state. You should validate internally in the constructor whatever that validation is.

Now, *what* constitutes validity is entirely up to your domain and how you intend to use the objects.

Perhaps rather than focusing on a fully-validated `Password` object, you create an `UnvalidatedPassword` object. It can internally set rules like "must be a string, at least 8 characters" and other basic validation. And this object is passed to a service for further checking.

Another option is that your `Password` object holds a flag for if it has been externally validated yet. Again, the object should be in a valid *state*, not necessarily be fully vetted by your domain logic. (Either are viable options, still!)

And still, sometimes a value object is just a nice way to wrap values and give them context. They don't always *need* perfect internal validation. Sending your `UnvalidatedPassword` to a service that ends up returning a `ValidPassword` object is yet another perfectly acceptable option.

The community is correct to close this as opinion-based; all of this is my opinion. But it's a cool topic.